Is there a way to force an NSObject to be allocated in stack or static memory?
I am asking this out of curiosity, because even if this can technically be done, this is almost certainly unsupported by Apple.
As far as I can tell, only NSString literals, and possibly NSDictionary literals can be allocated in static memory, because they can be used to initialize global/static NSString * objects, making them compile-time constants, whereas any behind-the-scenes dynamic allocation would be unsuitable for a compile-time constant initializer. For any other NSObject, the only supported way to have one is by using the alloc method.
If you try to declare a non-pointer to an NSObject, as you would a normal C struct if you wanted one allocated on the stack, such as NSWindow my_window; rather than NSWindow *my_window; a compile-time error results.
My question is, is there theoretically a way to have an NSObject allocated in stack or static memory? For example, to declare a stack or static buffer, and then 'trick' the Objective-C runtime into using that space for an NSObject? Something along the lines of:
unsigned char buffer[sizeof(NSWindow)]; // sizeof(NSWindow) is a compile-time error but you get the idea
NSWindow *window = buffer;
[window init];


Have you seen Objective C: Memory Allocation on stack vs. heap?

Theoretically it's possible, but no one guaranty stable behaviour. You need set at least pointer to [NSWindow class] at the beginning of yours buffer. Also I suggest to turn off ARC.  What you are trying to achieve with static NSObject?

@Cy-4AH I am curious if this can be done and how. How does setting the pointer to [NSWindow class] to the beginning of the buffer work?

@Willeke That basically is just to show that yes, Objective-C allocates everything on the heap, with a select few exceptions.

Setting aside your question (whether it's possible to trick the compiler), the reason the compiler errors on a local allocation of an object is that the ObjC object lifecycle model going all the way back rests on reference counting, which can't be done reliably when stuff could be unexpectedly "deallocated" by stack unwinding. So it's not just unsupported (thought it is that too) it's a guarantee of disaster. :)

@BenZotto Howver, if you disable ARC, and refrain from sending release to objects that were... questionably allocated, could that work? So the reference count in the objects are just ignored?

@CPlus Maybe! Try it and see what happens. I'm resisting answering directly because I don't actually know and more to the point, I guess, it's possible to make a C compiler (or your own code) do nearly any unnatural acts if you really want it to. But then, if you break the language rules, are you still writing in ObjC? Not really, right?

(More philosophically, C and by extension ObjC don’t work like more modern languages. In eg Python, if your code runs without errors then ipso facto it’s valid Python. C is more like a bunch of rusty ancient power tools in a box, and ObjC is a set of rules around how to use them. You can break the rules if you want, but there’s no one to complain to if you accidentally cut off your foot.)

All objects have pointer to the class object at the beginning of theirs buffer, to know whom to ask for function pointers.
